# Trying to write an inner join to filter out some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm currently struggling with carrying out some joins and hoping someone can shed some light on this.
    I have three tables: A,B,C

- Table C lists names of individuals
- Table A lists the food they like to eat
- Table B is the link to show what food in A a person likes from C (Our
  system was built without foreign keys! I know, it's a pain!)

What I'm trying to write is a query that will return a list of values from Table C which shows the individuals that don't like a specific food...say PFC

I have the following:

```
select * from table_c c
inner join table_b b
on c.name = b.bValue
inner join table_a a
on b.aValue = a.number
where a.value not in('PFC')
```

I'm assuming the joins are working but as table A has multiple values, the two extra rows are being returned. Is it possible to not show this client if one of the joins shows a food I don't want to see?

```
Table A
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Number         |     Value        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       McDs       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       KFC        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       PFC        |
|---------------------|------------------|

Table B
|---------------------|------------------|
|      bValue         |     aValue       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          John       |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|

Table C
|---------------------|
|      Name           |
|---------------------|
|          John       |
|---------------------|
```

I'm also using SQL Server 2013 if that makes a difference!

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from table_c c
where not exists (
  select 1 from table_b b inner join table_a a
  on b.aValue = a.number
  where b.bValue = c.name and a.value = 'PFC'
)
```

Comment: *given* after my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to aggregate by name:

```
SELECT
    c.Name
FROM table_c c
INNER JOIN table_b b
    ON c.Name = b.bValue
INNER JOIN table_a a
    ON b.aValue = a.Number
GROUP BY
    c.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Value = 'PFC' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

We could also try expressing this using an exists query:

```
SELECT
    c.Name
FROM table_c c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_b b
                  INNER JOIN table_a a
                      ON b.aValue = a.Number
                  WHERE c.Name = b.bValue AND
                        a.Value = 'PFC');
```